# Removing fragment using OnBackPressed() crashes app from NullPointerException

Tags: android, stack, fragment, back

I have a MainActivity and launching a fragment called  FragmentA using an OnClickListener. Inside FragmentA, I am launching FragmentB from the MainActivity using an OnArticleSelectedListener interface listener from inside FragmentA.

Now, I also have an OnBackPressed() that remove each fragment based on their tagID. It works fine when I am in FragmentA, however, when I launch FragmentA, then launch FragmentB using OnArticleSelected from inside FragmentA to launch it from the MainActivity and hit backspace while I am inside fragmentB I get a nullpointexception error :

```
   FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:651)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:472)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackImmediate(FragmentManager.java:487)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onBackPressed(FragmentActivity.java:179)
        at com.example.MainActivity.onBackPressed(MainActivity.java:247)
        at android.app.Activity.onKeyUp(Activity.java:2159)
        at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2647)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2389)
```

This is how I launch Fragment A:

```
@TargetApi(16)
public class MainActivity  extends FragmentActivity implements FragmentA.OnArticleSelectedListener {
RelativeLayout rl;
FrameLayout fl;
Button btn;
FragmentManager fragmentManager;
FragmentTransaction ft;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();


    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

  ...
  btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
    FragmentA newFragmentA = new FragmentA();
    ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    if (newFragmentA != null) {
        ft.remove(newFragmentA);
    }
    ft.replace(R.id.layoutholder, newFragmentA, "fragA");
    ft.addToBackStack("fragA");
    ft.commit();
}   
   ...
```

This is how I launch FragmentB through the MainActivity using an interface listener inside FragmentA:

```
  ...
   public void onArticleSelected(Uri uri) {
    FragmentB newFragmentB = new FragmentB();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putParcelable("uri", uri);
    FragmentB.setArguments(args);
    ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    if ( newFragmentB != null) {
        ft.remove( newFragmentB );
    }
   ft.replace(R.id.layoutholder, newFragmentB , "fragB");
   //Tried ft.add and it did not work either
   //ft.add(R.id.layoutholder, newFragmentB, "fragB");
   ft.addToBackStack("fragB");
   ft.commit();

};
```

Now I implemented an OnBackPressed() that will remove each fragment depending on it's fragment Tag. This is how I am doing it and I am getting a NullPointExceptionError after I launch fragmentA, then fragmentB and hitting the back press key on fragmentB.

Code for OnBackPressed() to remove fragmentB:

```
     ...
     public void onBackPressed() {
        getCurrentFragmentName();
             if (getCurrentFragmentName() == "fragB") {
                ft =  fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                FragmentB fragmentB = (FragmentB)fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("fragB");
                ft.remove("fragB");
                ft.commit();

    }
   super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to call `FragmentManager.popBackStack()` instead of removing the Fragment?

Comment: I discovered my error. I renamed the fragment ID and code to make it more generic. It was actually just a typo on my part. In FragmentB fragmentB = (FragmentB)fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("fragB"); I had the wrong Tag ID for FragB, so the code actually works and everything is good.

Comment: I see it now..`ft.remove("fragB");` You should call all these with the reference to the fragment and not with its tag.
Same with the    `ft.addToBackStack("fragB");`